# into nearest 15 minute

Tags: php, mysql, time

my table has a column which formated in mysql `time()` format.
when it's one value assign into php variable called `$preRemainOt`
i want to re arrange it into nearest 15 minute

```
function roundTime($whatTime)
{

echo $whatTime."=>";

$roundTime= round ( strtotime($whatTime) / 60 * 15  );

echo date("H:i:s",$roundTime)."<br>";

return date("H:i:s",$roundTime);
}

    $validOt =roundTime($preRemainOt);

<pre>
few bad result given from my try as follow:
$preRemainOt=>$validO
    03:43:00=>06:55:45
    01:05:00=>06:16:15
    02:00:00=>06:30:00
but result shuld be as follow:
$preRemainOt=>$validO
    03:43:00=>03:45:00
    01:05:00=>01:00:00
    02:00:00=>02:00:00
```

1.pls give me an idea.
2.what happen if my remaining ot value(`$preRemainOt`) exceed 24 hour
`ex:$preRemainOt='26:43:00'` is that doesn't matter to either php or mysql function.
what is the best mysql data type to store such a ot calculation

**update1**
after few advices i spilt my function in to three section

```
function secondToTime($timeStamp)
{
        $hours=intval($timeStamp / 3600);
        $mins=intval($timeStamp / 60) % 60;
        $secs=$timeStamp % 60;
    return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d",$hours, $mins, $secs);
}

function timeToSecond($time='00:00:00')
{
    list($hours, $mins, $secs) = explode(':', $time);
    $timeToSecond = ($hours * 3600 ) + ($mins * 60 ) + $secs;

    return $timeToSecond;
}

function roundTime($interval='00:00:00')
{
    $interval=timeToSecond($interval);
    $interval = intval($interval) + 450;
    $interval -= $interval % 900;
    return secondToTime($interval);
}
```

that because before the column value assigning into `$preRemainOt` variable ,there are another few steps.i change such two steps also,

```
function timeDiff($lastTime,$firstTime)
{
$firstTimetime=timeToSecond($firstTime);
$lastTime=timeToSecond($lastTime);
$timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

return secondToTime($timeDiff);
}

function timeAdd($firstTime,$lastTime)
{
$firstTimetime=timeToSecond($firstTime);
$lastTime=timeToSecond($lastTime);
$timeAdd=2*$lastTime-$firstTime;;
return secondToTime($timeAdd);
}
```

so i decided that it's dificult to use select `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. it would be change my whole script. 
**in this case  `"%d:%02d:%02d"` give nonsense**

Comment: 1 day = 24 hrs, and you want overtime(per day) > 1 day? hmm.. interesting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function roundTime($whatTime) {
    $time = strtotime($whatTime) + 450;
    return date("H:i:s", $time - $time % 900);
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually, based on your comment below, here's what I'd do. If this is a time interval and not a literal point in time, I would store the value in the database as an integer number of seconds instead of a DATETIME type. So 30:37:29 would be stored as 110249, since 110249 seconds is 30 hours, 37 minutes, and 29 seconds.

Then instead of passing "30:37:29" to this function, you would past 110249.  The function then would be:

```
function roundTime($interval) {
    $interval = intval($interval) + 450;
    $interval -= $interval % 900;
    return sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d",
        intval($interval / 3600),       // hours
        intval($interval / 60) % 60,    // minutes
        $interval % 60);                // seconds
}
```

If you've already stored a bunch of stuff in the database and absolutely cannot convert it to seconds instead of DATETIMEs, then in your query, instead of querying the DATETIME, use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function along with the function above.  In other words, instead of this:

```
SELECT id, name, preRemainOt, other_stuff...
```

Do this:

```
SELECT id, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(preRemainOt) AS preRemainOt, other_stuff...
```

Then pass the integer value of that column to the roundTime function instead of the value of the DATETIME.

Comment: The 900 is because 15 minutes is 900 seconds. The first line adding 450 effectively rounds the time up if you're more than 7.5 minutes (450 seconds) into a 15-minute block. The $time - $time % 900 calculation simply subtracts any remainder when the time is divided by 15 minutes, effectively discarding any extra minutes and seconds past the 15-minute mark.

Comment: ok well thanks can you explain what $time - $time % 900 substract doing thats would be my mistake

Comment: echo roundTime('30:37:29'); given bad answer.note $preRemainOt hold aaddition of worked hour(ot).this actually not real clock time.i mean clock time does not exceed '23:59:59'

Comment: $time % 900 gives you how many seconds have expired since the last 15-minute mark. By subtracting that number from the current time, you get the timestamp of the most recent 15-minute mark. For example, at 3:45:02, $time % 900 is 2 (for 2 seconds). Subtracting 2 seconds from 3:45:02 gives you 3:45. At 3:46:00, $time % 900 is 60 (60 seconds, or one minute). Subtracting 60 seconds from 3:46:00 again gives you 3:45. At 3:59:59, $time & 900 is 899. And so on.

Comment: strtotime() doesn't handle formats greater than "23:59:59".  If you want that, you need to parse out the hours, minutes, and seconds manually, probably using a regular expression.  Or better yet, if it doesn't matter whether your solution is implemented in PHP or MySQL, you should return UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) from your database instead of just date_column and pass that number to roundTime.  Use $whatTime instead of strtotime($whatTime) and it should work as you need.

Comment: I edited my answer above, this might better suit your needs.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: sprintf give d letter as out put

Comment: Did you resolve the issue just above?  The sprintf works fine for me. Are you sure you put the % sign in front of the d? Also, that's zero two d, not letter O two d.

Comment: i updated my new try. not your code cause  error.however change it into "%d:%0d:%0d" it gave some good result